# JS: Conventional structure for defining a callback function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I've written a simple function which triggers a callback function once it is done printing out a certain string. Are there any caveats I should be aware of when structuring my callbacks the way I did?

Also, what would be the best approach if the original function were to be subjected to asynchronicity?

**Code**:

```
// Output via console
var message = "hello there";

function typeOut(message, callback = null, i = 0) {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (i < message.length) {
      console.log(message.substring(0, i + 1));
      i++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
      callback();
    }
  }, 150);
  //callback;
}

function postDialog() {
  console.log('this is postdialog');
}

typeOut(message, postDialog);
```

**Fiddle**
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hf665ux6/1/)

Comment: It’s just a function. You call it. Looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two caveats:

- Don't use `null` as a default value. This will inevitably throw an exception when called. Either use no default value, requiring the caller to provide a function, or use a function that does nothing (e.g. `() => {}`) for the default value.
- The callback should always be the last parameter by convention. This makes calling a function with a long callback nicer, as all the arguments to the call are placed in the same spot, above the continuation.
  Given that your `i` parameter is optional as well, this might not be trivial. Potential workarounds I can think of:

  - Don't make `i` a parameter at all - you're not using it anyway. Also in a real-world use case where you "animate" a DOM node it's trivial to prepend a constant prefix to the animated node.
  - Overload your function to have multiple signatures, and decide depending on the `typeof` the second parameter whether its `i` or `callback`. This does get tedious though.

And in general, the advise for writing new code in a modern code base is of course to **use promises** instead of callbacks! They will dispose of both the above problems:

```
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}
async function typeOut(message, i = 0) {
  while (i < message.length) {
    await delay(150);
    i++;
    console.log(message.slice(0, i));
  }
}

var message = "hello there";
typeOut(message).then(function postDialog() {
  console.log('this is postdialog');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and prompt reply!